# Package installation in linux/ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

How do you compile and install bless hex editor or any other app without using package managers in linux(eg:aptitude,synaptic etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Goto http://home.gna.org/bless/downloads.html
2. Download the source
3. Extract the tarball by running `tar -xf bless-x.x.x.tar.gz` & `cd` into the extracted dir
4. Install dependencies, (you need Mono >= 1.1.14 and Gtk#2 >= 2.8) visit http://www.mono-project.com/download/ for more details on the installation process
5. Run `./configure`
6. Run `make`
7. Run `make install`

Comment: There was an issue while running bless.

 Missing method System.Type::op_Inequality(Type,Type) in assembly /usr/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll, referenced in assembly /usr/lib/mono/gac/glade-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gla‌​de-sharp.dll –

Is this because i installed wrong version of mono and gtk??